# Thread join c++ behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I'm synchronizing threads with `join()`, considering the order of the calls to join, why do I sometimes see the output of `t1` after `t2`?

i.e.

```
#include <thread>

void callFromThread(int id) {
    int i = 1000;
    while(i != 0) {
        printf("%s %d\n", "hi from thread", id);
        i--;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    std::thread t1 (callFromThread, 1);
    std::thread t2 (callFromThread, 2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    printf("%s\n", "bye from main!");
    return 0;
}
```

I could make sense of the behaviour if I had some interleaving in the beginning before the join calls, followed by all remaining t1 outputs, followed by the remaining t2 outputs. But, instead I'm seeing all t2 then all t1, or vice-versa.

Comment: Because the order of joining has nothing to do with the prior history of execution. If you want a specific execution order, why are you using threads?

Comment: @EJP, it took me a while to get it, but yes, this is the proper mental model of what's happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`join` affects the current thread you call `join`, not the thread which is joined.

basically, join makes the current thread wait for another thread to finish execution. it has no effect on when the other thread is scheduled to run, or on what order compared to other threads.

in your example, there is no guarantee which of the thread `t1` and `t2` will run and finish first. the only guarantee is that the main thread waits for `t1` first, then for `t2`, then logs a message to stdout.

Comment: Then why do I never see anything interleaved?

Comment: you mean interleaved on the console?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing either all 2, then 1 or all 1 then 2

Comment: probably since the function is so small, one thread is finished before other thread is scheduled by the OS. if you increase `i`, let's say to `10'000'000` you might see them interleaving

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you *join* doesn't determine or influence the order in which the threads are executed. So, the output from both threads could be in any order (or interleaved).

Comment: Although if I join immediately after I create a thread, they do indeed always execute in the order of the joins.

Comment: Yes. But if you do that, there are not threads in action (except main thread which is blocked by join), which is essentially sequential execution and defeats multi-threading.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that falsify your answer? It is in fact determining the order in which the threads are executed.

Comment: My answer is in the context of your code/question. Even then, "It is in fact determining the order in which the threads are executed" is false. When a thread A is *joining* with B, A is simply blocked until B is done -- this has no relation to the order of execution of threads.

Comment: You are correct, it is in the hands of the scheduler I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the calls doesn't mean that your output will be ordered the same way, and since you're executing the threads at "the same time" you can't control wich intruction is executed first in the CPU.

If you need to force that t1 make something before t2 just use [Semaphores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`join` doesn't have any effect on the thread that it's applied to. It just blocks the thread that called it until the thread that it's applied to finishes, and then continues execution. So the order of calls to `join` doesn't do anything to the order in which the threads are run.

Incidentally, in

```
std::thread t1(callFromthread, 1);
if (t1.joinable()) t1.join();
```

the test is redundant. Unless you call `detach`, `std::thread` objects are joinable.

Comment: Thanks for the info on `joinable()`.

Comment: Calling `join` on a non-joinable thread leads to undefined behaviour so I'd rather keep that redundant check. Other developers might throw in code in-between or the system might fail to launch a new thread.

Comment: @Patrik H, That was my thinking

Comment: @PatrikH - changing a thread to be detached is a major design change. Sure, you can write redundant code just in case you make such a change and forget that it has consequences throughout your code. But that's building in inefficiency in order to protect against a big process failure. I'd focus on fixing the process instead of applying band-aids.

Comment: @PatrikH - `std::thread::join` throws an exception if the thread is not joinable. And if the system fails to launch a new thread the constructor of `std::thread` throws an exception.

Comment: @PatrikH - sorry to post serial messages, but I think this warrants more serious thought. If some code is waiting for another thread to terminate, there's usually a reason for it; often it's waiting for a calculation to finish. If that thread gets changed so that it can no longer be joined, then the code that was waiting for it to finish can no longer function correctly. Simply blasting in a "don't wait" doesn't fix that problem.

Comment: @Pete, I get you and thanks for sharing your thoughts. You're saying that if the thread isn't joinable then we have a bigger problem and, most likely, there was an exception anyway. And that's probably true for many situations.
However, there might be a case where some other part of the code, maybe a callback, already did wait for the thread to finish so that thread won't be joinable any more.
This is why, in general, I'd keep that check before joining threads, it doesn't hurt, does it?If you have one of these rare cases where it's a performance hit, you can still remove it.

Comment: @PatrikH - it's not going to be a noticeable performance hit. It's a maintenance hit: everyone who reads the code will have to figure out why it's doing that. A bad analogy is always using `long long` for integer variables because you never know how large the values might be; in fact, you do know, and the code should reflect that knowledge.